# How to open new windows from main GUI and and pass vairable to the new window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an application with a Listbox with files and a menu. When I right-click an item from my listbox I have a menu for example Send. When I press 'Send' I want another window to open (I already have the new window) and in the new window I want to have the item-path that I selected (I have this path in the main window).

```
private void MenuItemSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{             
    if (listBoxFiles.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    { 
        return; 
    } 

    string filePath = (listBoxFiles.SelectedItem).ToString(); --- my file path
    StatisticsWindow sForm = new StatisticsWindow();
    sForm.ShowDialog(); -- open the new window
}
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: define an additional constructor in `IpStatisticsWindow` which accepts a `string filePath`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create a constructor for the window?

Instead of

```
new IpStatisticsWindow();
```

this:

```
new IpStatisticsWindow(filePath);
```

```
// In the IpStatisticsWindow class
public IpStatisticsWindow(string path)
{
    //do something with path
}
```

You could of course also create a property or a method which handles it, then  you can pass it there, e.g.

```
IPsForm.Path = filePath;
IPsForm.HandlePath(filePath);
```